# jQuery ui Datepicker if next day hasClass

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Is there a simple way to detect if the next day in the datepicker widget has the class 'disabled'?

I use the beforeShowDay: checkAvailability, calendar but extend it with half bookable dates. Now i want to check if the next day is disabled so users can't book.

Kind regards,

Stephan

```
switch ($durationValue) { 
    case 'weekend': 
        for (var i = 0; i < $myBadDates.length; i++) {
            if ($myBadDates[i] == $checkdate) {
                if ($.inArray($myBadDates[i], $halfavailable) !== -1) {

                    $returnclass = "halfavailable";
                } else {

                    $returnclass = "unavailable";
                }
            }
        }
        return [mydate.getDay() == 5, $returnclass];
        break;
    case 'midweek': 
        for (var i = 0; i < $myBadDates.length; i++) {
            if ($myBadDates[i] == $checkdate) {
                if ($.inArray($myBadDates[i], $halfavailable) !== -1) {
                    $returnclass = "halfavailable";
                } else {
                    $returnclass = "unavailable";
                }
            }
        }
        return [mydate.getDay() == 1, $returnclass];
        break;
    case 'week': 
        for (var i = 0; i < $myBadDates.length; i++) {
            if ($myBadDates[i] == $checkdate) {
                if ($.inArray($myBadDates[i], $halfavailable) !== -1) {
                    $returnclass = "halfavailable";
                } else {
                    $returnclass = "unavailable";
                }
            }
        }
        return [mydate.getDay() == 1, $returnclass];
        break;
    default: ''
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is a little hard to address. Something is missing, but I can't put my finger on it. You may want to create an example of your code in jsfiddle.net or something similar and include that in your post.

Comment: Thank you! I made a small demo. The demo works now. But i think it's a littlebit hackey.. I made a check if next day is in the myBadDates array. And for the week duration the six day. Maybe you have a better advise? http://codepen.io/amrz/pen/yOKpaG